# PHPExcel - How to style generated charts?

Tags: php, charts, phpexcel

I have followed several guides on creating different types of charts with PHPExcel but I couldn't find how to change basic stuff like changing the colors of bars/columns, lines, pie parts. My wild guess would be to do it in the third argument of the following constructor: `PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Data!$A$1', NULL, 1)` but even if it's a good guess there's no example how to do it and what can you do with it exactly.

[This is an example I used](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/33chartcreate-column.php)

1. How to change fill and outline of a data series?
2. How to change spacing (between chart bars for example)?
3. How to show data labels (not the legend but that value on top of each bar/column/point)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question

Answer (score 0):

To add data labels you can use it. It's worked for me.

```
$series->setPlotDirection( PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL );
```

Add these lines after above lines.

```
$layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout1->setShowVal( TRUE );
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea( $layout1, array( $series ) );
```